# Entity Framework 4 Updating child collections

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have created some basic sample code below. I am using the entity framework. I have a Parent object that has a collection of Children. I initally set up three children. When I am Updating the children I am removing one (John) and adding one (Sarah) the other two (Mary & Anne) remain the same. Is there any way to do this easily taking into account the database behind?

```
public class test
{       

    public test()
    {            
        Parent father = new Parent();

        father.Children.Add(new Child() { FirstName = "Mary" });
        father.Children.Add(new Child() { FirstName = "Anne" });
        father.Children.Add(new Child() { FirstName = "John" });  

        SaveEntityFramework();
    }

    public void UpdateChildren
    {
        Parent father = EntityFramework.GetParentByID(1);

        // Remove John
        father.Children.Remove(new Child() { FirstName = "John" });

        // Add Sarah
        father.Children.Add(new Child() { FirstName = "Sarah" }); 

        // Update or do Nothing Mary & Anne

        SaveEntityFramework();
    }
}

public class Parent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children;
}

public class Child
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have posted? Is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the father to your EntityFramework context? You're just creating it, adding the 3 children and then saving!

```
public test()
{            
    Parent father = new Perent();
    EntityFramework.Parents.Add(father);

    // Add children

    SaveEntityFramework();
}
```

Also, make sure what you get when you do `EntityFramework.GetParentByID(1);` you're getting the `Parent` you're looking for.

Hope this helps ;)